# Copy url clicked in webiew to clipboard

Tags: android, webview, clipboard, webviewclient

I am working on an application that downloads files. I have an edittext where the url of the file downloaded can be entered. Below it a button and below that, a webview. My webview is working and I am able to browse around by clicking links, but I want to allow for a user to long press a link, photo or other and present an option to save this url to the clipboard or even just insert it directly to the edittext. I haven't posted any code as I have not really done anything in this direction yet and I feel that the code I have is irrelevant. Should this be attempted inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading() of a webview client? Or elsewhere? And any suggestions on where to start or how to go about achieving this?

Comment: You could look at using a [ContextMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html)

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into it now.